# How to apply styling to expandIcon in MUI Accordion when Accordion is in expanded state?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, accordion

I am trying to remove `padding-top` from `ExpandIcon` in `Accordion` when `Accordion` is expanded. I am reading **MUI** docs how to target specific styling and states, but I have difficulties understanding the docs about styling. Can someone provide an example how to do this simple thing?

Here is how my accordion looks like:

[image]

And as you can see, the icon has `padding-top` which I want to remove, so that all elements are properly aligned.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `Accordion` component expand icon wrap in the `IconButton` component and MUI gave props `IconButtonProps` to pass the Icon button related props. So, first you have to create style the pass that style into `IconButton` component.

First create style using `makeStyle` function

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  iconBtn: {
    paddingTop: 0
  }
}));
```

then pass this class into `AccordionSummary` component property `IconButtonProps`

```
<AccordionSummary
  expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
  aria-controls="panel3bh-content"
  id="panel3bh-header"
  IconButtonProps={{ className: classes.iconBtn }}
>
```

codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-wescoff-329wj?file=/src/App.js

hacky way ->
if you want to center the All child element of the `AccordionSummary` component then add `align-items: center` because `AccordionSummary` made with `display: flex`. **warning** - may be this hacky way affect all `AccordionSummary` child elements.

Comment: Thanks @Amir! I am aligning children of AccordionSummary with align-items. Hower, the expandIcon is not affected by it. 

Okay. Your proposed solution brings me one step forward. I can apply styling to the IconButton, but I want to do it only when in expanded state

Comment: EDIT: unfortunately its not bringing me step forward because after applying css, the icon does not rotate anymore :/